# Rendering only the highlights of an object in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting

In the internal renderer, it's possible to turn off the diffuse on a light source while leaving on specular:

[image: in the light properties in Blender Render]

which gives the neat effect of only rendering the highlights on an object:

[image: Suzanne with only that light for illumination]

To my understanding, Cycles emulates real world physics in that the object's properties control how light interacts with it and the light itself doesn't play as much of a role. So I'm curious if there's a way to manipulate an object in Cycles so that it only shows highlights of any light source to simulate this effect?

I've seen some questions on the topic of specularity in Cycles, but only about adding it to light sources, not as a hypothetical solo source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can emulate equivalent results with Cycles *Ray Visibility* flags for the lamp object.

To a similar result to highlights you can turn off all components except *Glossy* for your lamp object.

[image]

Have in mind that this will only work on objects with materials with some sort of glossy reflection component. Purely diffuse, transparent, refractive or translucent materials will likely become totally unaffected by that light siurce